# Kafka Consumer failed CommitFailedError: Commit cannot be completed

Tags: python-3.x, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect, producer-consumer, consumer

I have one consumer with following configuration

```
def kafkaConnect(boot_server, g_id, topic):
    try:
        consumer = KafkaConsumer(bootstrap_servers=boot_server,
                                 auto_offset_reset='latest',
                                 # Set this property,if auto commit should happen.
                                 enable_auto_commit=True,
                                 auto_commit_interval_ms=999999999999,
                                 # This is how to control number of messages being read in each poll
                                 max_partition_fetch_bytes=135,
                                 #max_poll_interval_ms=300000,
                                 heartbeat_interval_ms=3000,
                                 session_timeout_ms=6000,
                                 consumer_timeout_ms=1000,
                                 group_id=g_id)
        consumer.subscribe([topic])
        print("Connection Created.........")
        logger.info("kafka Connection Created")

        return consumer
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(e)
```

consumer polling **data = consumerObj.poll(30000,100)** this much record in 30000 ms

```
while (True):
    data = consumerObj.poll(30000,100)
    a=data
    Commited_offset_value=0
    for packet in a:
        data_to_consume = list(data.values())
```

this consumer is consuming data from topic **xyz** and partion **0** but this is down frequetly after some time and need restart with updated group_id again and again why please suggest ?

below is error.

```
kafka.errors.CommitFailedError: CommitFailedError: Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member. This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured session.timeout.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time message processing. You can address this either by increasing the session timeout or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.
```

Comment: I have updated my configuration for kafka consumer and used synch commit call with pool custom param value and now its working perfect

Comment: datapackets=consumerObj.poll(timeout_ms=5000,max_records=100)

Comment: its working fine and perfect way .